# i want to limit the data inserting into database table on give date and time only 12

Tags: sql-server

```
create procedure SP_insert_test @name varchar(20), @emailid varchar(20), @trainer_name varchar(50), @training_date varchar(50), @training_time varchar(50), @gymname varchar(50) , @success int out as 
begin
   if(
   select
      count(id) 
   from
      Add_Booking_Fitness_Training 
   where
      training_time = @training_time) > 11 print N'Number of Booking Is Complete for this time and date plz book other time';
else
   insert into
      Add_Booking_Fitness_Training(memeber_name, member_emailid, trainer_name, training_date, training_time, gymname) 
   values
      (
         @name,
         @emailid,
         @trainer_name,
         @training_date,
         @training_time,
         @gymname
      )
      SELECT
         SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
      set
         @success = 1;
end
begin
      set
         @success = 0;
end
```

i have an table in which i want to insert data on give time only 12 member can insert at that time after that they get message list is full plz change the time for inserting i have create procedure its working when its reach number of 12 than its show me message but when i change the time its also show me the same message and not insert any data into database

like 26/04/2018,'6:00' i want to insert this value only 12 time after 12 this show me a message about the limit of number is reach plz change (time)

```
Create table Add_Booking_Fitness_Training ( id int identity primary key,
                                            memeber_name varchar(20),
                                            member_emailid varchar(20),
                                            trainer_name varchar(50),
                                            training_date varchar(50),
                                            training_time varchar(50),
                                            gymname varchar(50))
```

i just want to inserting a value into this table only 12 time for a give time like (6:00) if the number of inserting value reach to 12 than its show me the message number of values insert is reach to 12 please change the time.

i want input the value into table only 12 time for a give time 6:00Am when the value is insert into table 12 time than message come up for change time than insert value for change time

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I am completely guessing here, I still don't really know what you're asking.

I ***think*** the OP's statement of *"i want input the value into table only 12 time for a give time 6:00Am when the value is insert into table 12 time than message come up for change time than insert value for change time."* means that they only want a time to appear in the table up to 12 times. If it appears more than that, the `INSERT` fails.

This can be achieved with a check constraint and a scalar function. So, as a very simple example:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO
--Create a very simple table
CREATE TABLE SampleTable (TrainingTime datetime2(0));
GO

--Create the scalar function
CREATE FUNCTION TrainingAtTime (@TrainingTime datetime2(0))
RETURNS INT
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @Trainees int;

    SELECT @Trainees = COUNT(*)
    FROM SampleTable
    WHERE TrainingTime = @TrainingTime;

    RETURN @Trainees;
END

GO
--Add the check constraint
ALTER TABLE SampleTable ADD CONSTRAINT MaxTrainees CHECK (dbo.TrainingAtTime(TrainingTime) <= 12) ;
GO
--Insert first trainee
INSERT INTO SampleTable
VALUES ('2018-04-26T06:00:00');
--It works
SELECT TrainingTime, COUNT(*) AS Trainees
FROM SampleTable
GROUP BY TrainingTime;
GO
--insert 11 more
INSERT INTO SampleTable
VALUES ('2018-04-26T06:00:00'),
       ('2018-04-26T06:00:00'),
       ('2018-04-26T06:00:00'),
       ('2018-04-26T06:00:00'),
       ('2018-04-26T06:00:00'),
       ('2018-04-26T06:00:00'),
       ('2018-04-26T06:00:00'),
       ('2018-04-26T06:00:00'),
       ('2018-04-26T06:00:00'),
       ('2018-04-26T06:00:00'),
       ('2018-04-26T06:00:00');
--It works
SELECT TrainingTime, COUNT(*) AS Trainees
FROM SampleTable
GROUP BY TrainingTime;
GO
--Try to insert another
INSERT INTO SampleTable
VALUES ('2018-04-26T06:00:00');
--It fails
SELECT TrainingTime, COUNT(*) AS Trainees
FROM SampleTable
GROUP BY TrainingTime;
GO
--Use a different time
INSERT INTO SampleTable
VALUES ('2018-04-26T08:00:00');
--it works
SELECT TrainingTime, COUNT(*) AS Trainees
FROM SampleTable
GROUP BY TrainingTime;
GO

--Clean up
DROP TABLE SampleTable; 
DROP FUNCTION TrainingAtTime;
GO
```

If this isn't what you're after, unfortunately I don't understand your requirements due the the language barrier (and absence of a question).